# How use the FORMAT part of the sscanf function (or how to use the sscanf function in general)

Tags: c

I have encountered the following line in a program. From reading the manual, I know that sscanf copies from wherever argv[2] is pointed to, but I'm not sure why the FORMAT had been specified as %d and, at the same time, %c (I've seen other examples where there are more format specifiers included in the double quotations ). Is it because sscanf writes a decimal to the struct element "%g.number", a character to "%c"? Thanks!

```
sscanf(argv[2], " %d %c", &g.number, &c)
```

Comment: [. **Free** knowledge!](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

Comment: Are you sure you want the extra space before the `%d`?

Comment: yes, the space is present in the code

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Reading from argv[2], one integer to g.number and one char to c.

For example argv[2] could be "123 a"

Comment: The very first integer? say if the string was "Rudolph is 12 years old" then %d reads 12 and %c read the "R"?

Comment: No that's not possible. In this case you will get some rubbish. The string must be formatted as you specified, the program is not that smart to parse it for you.

Comment: say if argv[2] is "a" then "%d %c" would convert "a" to 97 (ASCII) then the character "a" once again?

Comment: No. The behavior is undefined. Think about that - a %d is 4 bytes long, argv[2] is just 2 bytes "a\0". So the %d will involve some rubbish and the %c will not get anything.

Comment: While that sounds right, it doesn't quite work that way.  what will happen is that nothing will get scanned unless the first input is a number.  If the first input is a number and there is no other input ie "9" then g.number will be assigned the value of 9 and nothing will be assigned to c, and the return value of sscanf will be one.  The number of bytes held in the string has no bearing on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

What it is specifying is zero or more white space characters followed by a number followed by zero or more white space characters, then a character.  It puts the values of the number in g.number and the character in c.  I'm not sure why it scans for a number then a character, but if the input does not start with a number, then nothing will be assigned to either variables and the return value of sscanf will be zero, which is how many variables it scanned in.  If it fails then the value in g.number will be whatever is in the memory slot it occupies which could be anything, hence undefined.